# GPUImage video camera imageView is black

Tags: ios, video, camera, subview, gpuimage

So I've just discovered gpuImage & I'm trying to do some basic video filtering as per the [gpuimage github readme](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage#filtering-live-video)....

I've more or less copied their code identically, but when I add the gpuImageView to my ViewController as a subview, it just appears as a black screen. Could anyone shed some light onto why the image doesn't appear? Thanks!!!

```
GPUImageVideoCamera *videoCamera = [[GPUImageVideoCamera alloc]
                                    initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480
                                    cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];

videoCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;

GPUImageSepiaFilter *filter = [[GPUImageSepiaFilter alloc] init];
[filter setIntensity: 0.5];

GPUImageView *filteredVideoView = [[GPUImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

[videoCamera addTarget:filter];

[filter addTarget:filteredVideoView];

[self.view addSubview:filteredVideoView];

[videoCamera startCameraCapture];
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind ya'll, I sorted it.

The pointers to the camera & filter were just going out of scope and getting cleaned up! I had to make them a @property, which is pretty obvious in hindsight. lol

Thanks anyway